# How can i make link with selected range in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using word2003 document for processing in my document i have to made link with two string variables (Not in the sense Footnotes and Endnotes)

{Page 1} Best quote from David Brinkley[1]

{Page 6}**[1] A successful person is one who can lay a firm foundation with the bricks that others throw at him**

I suppose to use Footnote/Endnote for the value [1] to link but it cause some changes while editing the the Footnote/Endnote. Is there any other way to make link between the selected string?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this, but you could bookmark the text on page 6, then add a hyperlink on page 1 that points to the bookmark. This can be done without VBA code:

1. Select the text for the bookmark on page 6.
2. Insert/Bookmark
3. Name the bookmark and add it
4. Select the text for the bookmark on page 1.
5. Insert/Hyperlink
6. Click the Bookmark button and select the bookmark in the list

The equivalent in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddHyperlinkToBookmark()
    Dim oBookmark As Bookmark
    Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink

    '***** Add code to select text for bookmark

    Set oBookmark = ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add("BookmarkName", Selection.Range)

    '***** Add code to select text for link

    Set oHyperlink = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Selection.Range, "", "BookmarkName")

    Set oBookmark = Nothing
    Set oHyperlink = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did it work? If so you should close the quesion by clicking the checkmark beside it.